# Change "select" item according to button click HTML JS

Tags: javascript, html

I am changing the visibility of  according to the selected value from "select". 
I want to add a button to select a specific value from select, but it is not working with me.
When I click on the button, it select the value and return to the original value before clicking the button.
This is my code

```html
<html>
<head>
<meta content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
http-equiv="content-type">
<title>Get Food</title>
<script type="text/javascript">
function nearMe()
{
document.getElementById("list").value = "1"
}

function showDiv(value){

switch (value) {
case '0':
document.getElementById('1').style.display = 'none';
document.getElementById('2').style.display = 'none';
document.getElementById('3').style.display = 'none';
document.getElementById('4').style.display = 'none';
break
case '1':
document.getElementById('1').style.display = '';
document.getElementById('2').style.display = 'none';
document.getElementById('3').style.display = 'none';
document.getElementById('4').style.display = 'none';
break;
case '2':
document.getElementById('1').style.display = 'none';
document.getElementById('2').style.display = '';
document.getElementById('3').style.display = 'none';
document.getElementById('4').style.display = 'none';
break;
case '3':
document.getElementById('1').style.display = 'none';
document.getElementById('2').style.display = 'none';
document.getElementById('3').style.display = '';
document.getElementById('4').style.display = 'none';
break;
case '4':
document.getElementById('1').style.display = 'none';
document.getElementById('2').style.display = 'none';
document.getElementById('3').style.display = 'none';
document.getElementById('4').style.display = '';
break;
default :
break;
}

}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div><img style="float: left; width: 88px; height: 88px;"
alt="Neqsat Khair Logo" src="neqsatKhair.jpeg"><br>
<h1 style="text-align: center;">App name</h1>
</div>
<hr> <br>
<h3> H3 </h3>
close to: <br>
<br>
<form action="123.html">
<select id="list" name="area" style="width: 200px;"
onchange="showDiv(this.value)">
<option value="0">Choose an area</option>
<option value="1">City1</option>
<option value="2">City2</option>
<option value="3">City3</option>
<option value="4">City4</option>
</select>
<br>
<br>
<button onclick="nearMe()">Near me</button> <br>
<br>
<div id="1" style="display: none;"><br>
<p> 1 </p>
  </div>
<div id="2" style="display: none;">
<p> 2 </p>
  </div>
<div id="3" style="display: none;">
<p> 3 </p>
  <div id="4" style="display: none;">
<p> 4 </p>
  </div>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: _“When I click on the button, it select the value and return to the original value before clicking the button”_ - That’s because clicking the button _submits_ your form. Go research what the appropriate `type` attribute is for a button that should _not_ submit the form.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you are setting a value to the dropdown box programatically you need to call the onchange function programatically.

```
function nearMe()
{
document.getElementById("list").value = "1"
document.getElementById("list").onchange();
}
```

add the line document.getElementById("list").onchange(); in your nearme function. I hope i answered your question.

```js
function nearMe(){
document.getElementById("list").value = "1"
document.getElementById("list").onchange();
}

function showDiv(value){

switch (value) {
case '0':
document.getElementById('1').style.display = 'none';
document.getElementById('2').style.display = 'none';
document.getElementById('3').style.display = 'none';
document.getElementById('4').style.display = 'none';
break
case '1':
document.getElementById('1').style.display = '';
document.getElementById('2').style.display = 'none';
document.getElementById('3').style.display = 'none';
document.getElementById('4').style.display = 'none';
break;
case '2':
document.getElementById('1').style.display = 'none';
document.getElementById('2').style.display = '';
document.getElementById('3').style.display = 'none';
document.getElementById('4').style.display = 'none';
break;
case '3':
document.getElementById('1').style.display = 'none';
document.getElementById('2').style.display = 'none';
document.getElementById('3').style.display = '';
document.getElementById('4').style.display = 'none';
break;
case '4':
document.getElementById('1').style.display = 'none';
document.getElementById('2').style.display = 'none';
document.getElementById('3').style.display = 'none';
document.getElementById('4').style.display = '';
break;
default :
break;
}

}
```

```html
<html>
<head>
<meta content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
http-equiv="content-type">
<title>Get Food</title>


</head>
<body>
<div><img style="float: left; width: 88px; height: 88px;"
alt="Neqsat Khair Logo" src="neqsatKhair.jpeg"><br>
<h1 style="text-align: center;">App name</h1>
</div>
<hr> <br>
<h3> H3 </h3>
close to: <br>
<br>
<form action="123.html">
<select id="list" name="area" style="width: 200px;"
onchange="showDiv(this.value)">
<option value="0">Choose an area</option>
<option value="1">City1</option>
<option value="2">City2</option>
<option value="3">City3</option>
<option value="4">City4</option>
</select>
<br>
<br>
<button onclick="nearMe()">Near me</button> <br>
<br>
<div id="1" style="display: none;"><br>
<p> 1 </p>
  </div>
<div id="2" style="display: none;">
<p> 2 </p>
  </div>
<div id="3" style="display: none;">
<p> 3 </p>
  <div id="4" style="display: none;">
<p> 4 </p>
  </div>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you ... but it didnt work .... I am using Chrome browser ... and when I click the button, the <div> and reset it again and the select is back to choose an area

Comment: replace the action="123.html" to action="#" then try this

Comment: Hi did you try that

Answer (score 0):

Simply add `nearMe()` inside the `function showDiv(value){}` function you getting like this

```html
<html>
<head>
<meta content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
http-equiv="content-type">
<title>Get Food</title>
<script type="text/javascript">
function nearMe()
{
document.getElementById("list").value = "1"
}

function showDiv(value){
nearMe()
switch (value) {
case '0':
document.getElementById('1').style.display = 'none';
document.getElementById('2').style.display = 'none';
document.getElementById('3').style.display = 'none';
document.getElementById('4').style.display = 'none';
break
case '1':
document.getElementById('1').style.display = '';
document.getElementById('2').style.display = 'none';
document.getElementById('3').style.display = 'none';
document.getElementById('4').style.display = 'none';
break;
case '2':
document.getElementById('1').style.display = 'none';
document.getElementById('2').style.display = '';
document.getElementById('3').style.display = 'none';
document.getElementById('4').style.display = 'none';
break;
case '3':
document.getElementById('1').style.display = 'none';
document.getElementById('2').style.display = 'none';
document.getElementById('3').style.display = '';
document.getElementById('4').style.display = 'none';
break;
case '4':
document.getElementById('1').style.display = 'none';
document.getElementById('2').style.display = 'none';
document.getElementById('3').style.display = 'none';
document.getElementById('4').style.display = '';
break;
default :
break;
}

}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div><img style="float: left; width: 88px; height: 88px;"
alt="Neqsat Khair Logo" src="neqsatKhair.jpeg"><br>
<h1 style="text-align: center;">App name</h1>
</div>
<hr> <br>
<h3> H3 </h3>
close to: <br>
<br>
<form action="123.html">
<select id="list" name="area" style="width: 200px;"
onchange="showDiv(this.value)">
<option value="0">Choose an area</option>
<option value="1">City1</option>
<option value="2">City2</option>
<option value="3">City3</option>
<option value="4">City4</option>
</select>
<br>
<br>
<button onclick="nearMe()">Near me</button> <br>
<br>
<div id="1" style="display: none;"><br>
<p> 1 </p>
  </div>
<div id="2" style="display: none;">
<p> 2 </p>
  </div>
<div id="3" style="display: none;">
<p> 3 </p>
  <div id="4" style="display: none;">
<p> 4 </p>
  </div>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

No need to write too much code which can be done by simple way.

```js
function nearMe()
{
  alert("You set the value as 'City1'");
  document.getElementById("list").value = "1";
  document.getElementById("selected_city").innerHTML = 1;
}

function showDiv(value){
  document.getElementById("selected_city").innerHTML = value;
}
```

```html
<select id="list" name="area" style="width: 200px;"
onchange="showDiv(this.value)">
<option value="">Choose an area</option>
<option value="1">City1</option>
<option value="2">City2</option>
<option value="3">City3</option>
<option value="4">City4</option>
</select>
<br/>
<button type="button" onclick="nearMe()">Near me</button>
<div id="selected_city"></div>
```

Comment: Thank you for your anser, but in my real code the <div> contains many things other than just a number ... I asked here as one number just to make it simple